# Firebase and Angular 2 how to get children count with read restriction

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I have client document with linked reservation, created as Google suggested:

```
clients: {
    clientkey1: {
        name: Some Name,
        reservations: {
            reskey1: true,
            reskey2: true
        }
    }
}
```

and reservations doc:

```
reservations: {
    reskey1: {
        clientKey: clientkey1,
        doctorName: Doctor Name
    },
    reskey2: {
        clientKey: clientkey1,
        doctorName: Doctor Name
    },
    reskey3: {
        clientKey: clientkey2,
        doctorName: Doctor Name
    },
    reskey4: {
        clientKey: clientkey3,
        doctorName: Doctor Name
    },
    reskey5: {
        clientKey: empty
    }
}
```

Now in client's App I have to list his reservations and also count all reservations to get info about which part he occupies and stuff like how many places are still available. I can download all reservation and filter with clientKey, but how to avoid downloading whole data with other clients' reservations data ?

Is there a way to download only keys from reservations ?

Answer (score 0):

No, but [you could count with Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/child-count).

```
exports.countReservations = functions.database.ref('/reservations/{id}').onWrite(event => {
  const collectionRef = event.data.ref.parent;
  const countRef = collectionRef.parent.child('reservationCount');

  return countRef.transaction(current => {
    if (event.data.exists() && !event.data.previous.exists()) {
      return (current || 0) + 1;
    } else if (!event.data.exists() && event.data.previous.exists()) {
      return (current || 0) - 1;
    }
  });
});
```